# How to use a 'this' in the selector in queryselectorall

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to use some kind of 'this' in the selector in querySelectorAll()?

Explanation: If I use:

```
var _childlist = document.querySelectorAll("#treeIC > li");
```

I got the result I wish for the first level in my tree.

But if I use:

```
var _ICtree = document.getElementById("treeIC");
var _childlist = _ICtree.querySelectorAll("li");
```

I got all the li tags nested down the tree. If I wrote:

```
var _childlist = _ICtree.querySelectorAll("> li"); // or
var _childlist = _ICtree.querySelectorAll("this > li");
```

it doesn't work.

I need to use a recursive call in my implementation and that why I need it. I know how do a workaround, but I would like to know if there is a way to use a 'this' in querySelectorAll() and write a more clean code.

Comment: No, you can't use `this` as an argument to `querySelectorAll()` as it takes a string for its argument.  You can do `this.querySelectorAll()` if `this` is a DOM element.

Comment: Why don't you convert the NodeList into an array and use `map` or `forEach`? They provide a `this` built -in.

Comment: In [supporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility), you could use the `:scope` pseudo-selector. But it will throw an error on browsers that don't support it. An other alternative would be a function like 
 
`Array.prototype.filter.call(parentElement.children, function(el){return el.matches(selector)})` which would return an Array an not a live NodeList.